# Make a button that increments numbers on every click

Tags: javascript, html, button, increment

Here is my html and JavaScript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>People Increment</title>
  

<script>
    let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el")
    console.log (countEl)
    let count = 0;

    function increment() {
        count = count + 1;
        console.log(count)
        countEl.innerText= count
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>Lets See How Many Time You've Have Clicked On this Button</h1>
    <h1 id="count-el"></h1>
    <button onclick="increment()">Increment</button>

</body>
</html>
```

when I remove the line

```
countEl.innerText= count.
```

It shows the right output but in console-inspect menu. Need a solution that somehow don't use EventListner

Comment: Your `count-el` does not exist when the code runs, Wrap in `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded, () => { ... your code ... });`

Comment: If you already checked the console, you should have seen an error message saying something like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText')" there.

Comment: `Need a solution that somehow don't use EventListner` ??? why... If you are not allowed the eventlistener, then you need to move the code to after the HTML, before the `</body>` tag

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I did'nt knew that, now I'll look forward to add the event listener, and I appreciate your quick response. Have a great day!